# Does MemoryBarrier really ensure refresh values?

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile, cpu-cache

Albahari in his marvelous book C# in a nutshell (a free chapter is available online), talks about how memory barrier allows us to get a "refresh" value. His example is:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        bool complete = false;
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            bool toggle = false;
            while (!complete)
            {
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
        });
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        complete = true;
        t.Join();        // Blocks indefinitely
    }
```

This blocks indefinitely as he suggests if you build in release mode. He offers few solutions to solve this block. Use Thread.MemoryBarrier in the while loop, use lock or make "complete" volatile static field.

I would agree with the volatile field solution as volatile enforces a direct memory read rather than a register read for JIT. However I believe this optimization has nothing to do with fences and memory barriers. It's just a matter of JIT optimization as in if JIT prefers reading it from memory or from a register. Actually instead of using MemoryBarrier, any method call "convinces" JIT not to use the register at all as in:

```
    class Program
    {
        [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public static bool Toggle(bool toggle)
        {
            return !toggle;
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            bool complete = false;
            var t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                bool toggle = false;
                while (!complete)
                {
                    toggle = Toggle(toggle);
                }
            });
            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            complete = true;
            t.Join();        // Blocks indefinitely
        }
    }
```

Here I am making a dummy toggle call. And from the assembly code generated I can clearly see JIT uses direct memory access for reading the "complete" local variable. Thus my assumption, at least on intel CPU and considering the compiler optimizations, MemoryBarrier has no role in terms of "refreshness". MemoryBarrier just aquires a full fence the preseve the order and that's it. Am I correct to think that way?

Comment: There are *two* requirements.  First one is to convince the jitter that it can't keep the variable stored in a register.  It gives up pretty easily, a method call can be enough.  Declaring it *volatile* is a sledgehammer that is effective on x86.  Or the natural way from a sync sensitive piece of code, like lock or Interlocked.  Note how inserting Interlocked.Equals(toggle, false) is enough.  The other is the memory access ordering you get from a barrier, Volalite.Read/Write are the most effective ones.  Which in turn forces the jitter to treat the variable volatile, so one is enough

Comment: I agree with you: this has nothing to do with memory barriers.

Comment: @HansPassant, `volatile` is one valid approach, just as good as `Volatile.Read`/`Volatile.Write` but in a way you can't forget to use them.  Also, `Interlocked.Equals` is just the static `Object.Equals`, it's clearly not enough for anything related to synchronization.

Comment: Don't believe me, take it [from this guy](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/12/04/sayonara-volatile/).

Comment: @HansPassant, that post is a strong opinion on the `volatile` annotation.  The author comes up with a replacement which uses another evil, [mutable structs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs/), perhaps the main reason .NET framework itself doesn't use it.  I suppose another one is that the `volatile` annotation, however imperfect, has proven enough to not miss volatile accesses, whereas using `Volatile.*` is prone to missing even a single critical access that should be volatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I would agree with the volatile field solution as volatile enforces a direct memory read rather than a register read for JIT. However I believe this optimization has nothing to do with fences and memory barriers.**

Volatile reads and writes are described in **ECMA-335, I.12.6.7**. Important parts of this section:

> A volatile read has “acquire semantics” meaning that the read is guaranteed to occur prior to any references to memory that occur after the read instruction in the CIL instruction sequence.  A volatile write has “release semantics” meaning that the write is guaranteed to happen after any memory references prior to the write instruction in the CIL instruction sequence.

> A conforming implementation of the CLI shall guarantee this semantics of volatile operations.

and

> **An optimizing compiler** that converts CIL to native code **shall not remove any volatile operation, nor shall it coalesce multiple volatile operations into a single operation.**

Acquire and release semantics for x86 and x86-64 architectures doesn't require any memory barriers (because the hardware memory model is not weaker than required by volatile semantics). But for ARM architecture JIT must emit half-fences (one direction memory barriers).

So, in that example with volatile everything works because of optimization restriction. And with MemoryBarrier it works because compiler can't optimize read of that variable into a single read outside the loop, because this read can't cross the MemoryBarrier.

But the code

```
while (!complete)
{
    toggle = Toggle(toggle);
}
```

is allowed to be optimized into something like this:

```
var tmp = complete;
while (!tmp)
{
    toggle = Toggle(toggle);
}
```

The reason why it doesn't happen in case of method call is that for some reason optimization was not applied (but it can be applied). So, this code is fragile and implementation-specific, because it relies not on standard, but on implementation details which might be changed.

Comment: Great answer! Though I wish there were some sort of documentation how specifically MemoryBarrier alters the behavior of JIT. Having that said, what you say is logical. Storing the value into a register would make that read value retained across the memory boundary which defeats the barrier's purpose in the first place.

Comment: @OnurGumus details on how exactly jit behaves is an implementation details, but you can read source code of RyuJIT or it's documentation on github. Anyway there is ECMA-335 specification that describes what you can rely on and what can possibly happen.

Comment: Also, even though the C# compiler might not optimize the `while (!complete)` statement, the JIT compiler may still perform such optimization, and if it doesn't, a weak memory model hardware architecture might still read the same value from `complete` over and over, when lacking synchronization.

Comment: I believe for ARM JIT currently uses full barrier (DMB) for both reads and writes.